# Cookie Authentication expiration does not re-route to login page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using asp.net core 1.0, and I have ASP Identity.  I want to use the cookies to set up a cookie expiration so that when the page has been idle for the 20 minutes time span, it will reroute to the login page.  Currently it does not.
My setup:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

add identity as:

```
  services.AddIdentity<CRAMSUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") &&
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CRAMSContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**How do I set it up so that it will reroute to the login page while sitting idle for like an hour?**

Comment: By reroute do you mean by magic, without the user doing anything or a new request being sent?

Comment: @blowdart, yes by magic or detection of session time out, or it can be set to say 15 minutes of inactivity. For instance, I will sit at a page on idle for more than 20+ minutes and the authentication will logout but the page will remain on the same page. Then in my console, it'll error and say unauthorized. Instead of staying on the same page, I would prefer it to refresh and go straight to a page that says "session timed out, please log back in".

Comment: By magic won't work. You'd have to have some javascript polling a URL, which, when the cookie expires, returns a 403 which you detect and then you can redirect in the javascript.

Comment: So a javascript code that watches for the 403 error then set url to you've been logged out? Do you think you could give an example @blowdart, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Sliding Expiration**: see [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html#controlling-cookie-options)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
});
```

Sliding Expiration on cookies work this way: On authentication, an absolute expiration time is set (i.e. now+60Min). On subsequent requests the expiration time should be reset to the new Now+60min, but this renewal is not done on each request because that would be a waste of bandwidth. So only after X% of that sliding expiration has past the cookie is renewed with the new expiration date. According to the docs, on ASP.NET X is 50% of the `ExpirationTimeSpan` (30 minutes).

Comment: Does this only extend the timeout time to 60 minutes?

Comment: It sets the cookie timeout to 60 minutes. If the user makes another request more than 30 minutes later, it will refresh the cookie and the timeout.

Comment: Great, I will leave the test over night to see what happens in the AM.

Comment: I've updated the answer. For testing I recommend you use a TimeSpan of 3 minutes or so...

Comment: I am still having trouble with it redirecting.

Comment: What kind of trouble? how is it failing vs what is your desired behaviour?

Comment: While I add the app.UseCookieAuthentication, do I add it before or after app.UseIdentity()?  For instance, I will sit at a page on idle for more than 20+ minutes and the authentication will logout but the page will remain on the same page.  Then in my console, it'll error and say unauthorized.  Instead of staying on the same page, I would prefer it to refresh and go straight to a page that says "session timed out, please log back in".  I attempted to do a auto-refresh every 21 minutes using jquery but it'll either stayed logged in, or it won't refresh probably because the session timed out.